# Why is my JAVA code for solving sudoku using backtracking not giving any solution?

Tags: java, backtracking, sudoku

This is a code in JAVA for solving the sudoku problem for any 9*9 sudoku grid using backtracking. It is not printing any output. I am not able to find the mistake in this. Please help. I have included one of the sample input int the main function in the form of a 9*9 grid. is_safe function if it is safe to put the selected character there by checking the same row, same column and the corresponding 3*3 grid. The base case checks when cr becomes 9, that is, reaches the end of board and cl becomes 0, that is, when we reach out of the board. Then a possible solution may have been found. We print the board at that point and return to the calling function. It seems logically correct but it is not printing any output.

````
    public static boolean is_safe(int mat[][],int cr,int cl,int i)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<mat.length;k++)
        {
            if(k!=cl&&mat[cr][k]==i)
            return false;
            if(k!=cr&&mat[k][cl]==i)
            return false;
        }
        int row=cr-cr%3;
        int col=cl-cl%3;
        for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            for(int l=0;l<3;l++)
            {
                if(mat[k+row][l+col]==i)
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void print(int mat[][])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<mat.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<mat[0].length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(mat[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void func(int mat[][],int cr,int cl)
    {
        if(cr==mat.length&&cl==0)
        {
            print(mat);
            return;
        }
        int i=cr,j=cl;
        if(mat[cr][cl]!=0)
        {
            if(cl+1==9)
            func(mat,cr+1,0);
            else
            func(mat,cr,cl+1);
        }
        else{
        for(int k=1;k<=9;k++)
        {
            if(is_safe(mat,i,j,k))
            {
                mat[i][j]=k;
                if(j+1==mat.length)
                func(mat,i+1,0);
                else
                func(mat, i, j+1);
                mat[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mat[][]={{3,0,6,5,0,8,4,0,0},
                     {5,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,8,7,0,0,0,0,3,1},
                     {0,0,3,0,1,0,0,8,0},
                     {9,0,0,8,6,3,0,1,5},
                     {0,5,0,0,9,0,6,0,0},
                     {1,3,0,0,0,0,2,5,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,4},
                     {0,0,5,2,0,6,3,0,0}};
        func(mat,0,0);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a [MRE], with example input, expected and observed output.

Comment: You should just use debugging with breakpoints to check to see the flow of the code, and where it is ending currently compared to where you want it to end.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Notwithstanding the questionable style here (variable names, spaces between operators, etc), this code is logically fine. The problem is the sudoku grid is unsolvable. Compare it with the matrix from [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudoku-backtracking-7/) and you'll see that `{9,0,0,8,6,3,0,1,5}` should be `{9,0,0,8,6,3,0,0,5}`. Voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print method is never called! It seems that the sodoku is not solvable!

With the following input your code works fine:

```
{{3,0,6,5,0,8,4,0,0},
{5,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,8,7,0,0,0,0,3,1},
{0,0,3,0,1,0,0,8,0},
{9,0,0,8,6,3,0,0,5},
{0,5,0,0,9,0,6,0,0},
{1,3,0,0,0,0,2,5,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,4},
{0,0,5,2,0,6,3,0,0}};
```

You can also change your print method to make it more readable:

```
public static void print(int mat[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.stream(mat[i])
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", stringList));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3 1 6 5 7 8 4 9 2
5 2 9 1 3 4 7 6 8
4 8 7 6 2 9 5 3 1
2 6 3 4 1 5 9 8 7
9 7 4 8 6 3 1 2 5
8 5 1 7 9 2 6 4 3
1 3 8 9 4 7 2 5 6
6 9 2 3 5 1 8 7 4
7 4 5 2 8 6 3 1 9
```